# Why was the stack around char array was corrupted

Tags: c++, arrays, char, stack

I'm pretty new to C++, coming from Java. I'm working on just extracting the first word from a Char array, so I figure that creating a new array to hold all the first word chars and transferring them till the loop runs into a space in the sentence would work. Here is the code:

```
void execute(){
//start with getting the first word
char first_word[20];
int i = 0;
while (input[i] != ' '){ // input is a char array declared and modified with cin, obtaining the command.
    first_word[i] = input[i];
    i++;
}
print(first_word + ' ' + 'h' + ' ' + 'h' + 'a');
}
```

When trying to execute this, I get the error "Stack around the variable 'first_word' was corrupted". Why is this happening?

Comment: Where does input come from? Probably it has more than 20 characters. And I don't understand your print function. + on an array does not concatenate strings. You should use `std::string` instead if you want easy strings like Java.

Comment: `first_word + ' '` doesn't do what you think it does. `first_word` is a char array, not a string.

Comment: @NeilKirk the input comes from another method that simply takes 'cin >> input' and then makes them all lower case. I dont know if that's the right way to do things.

Comment: `std::string first_word(input, std::find(input, input + input_size, ' '); print(first_word + " h ha");`

Comment: `cin >> input` is not valid if `input` is a character array (well, it is valid, but it does not do what you think it does). Change `input` to `std::string` instead, but then you have to re-write `execute()` to work with `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin >> input` doesn't do what you think it does when `input` is a character array.  The `>>` operator cannot read into a character array, you have to use `cin.getline()` or `cin.read()` instead. So you are actually causing undefined behavior by processing invalid memory.

Even if it did work, you are also not doing any bounds checking.  If `input` has more than 20 characters before encountering a space character (or worse, does not contain a space character at all), you will write past the end of `first_word` into surrounding memory.

If you really want to code in C++, don't use character arrays for strings.  That is how C handles strings.  C++ uses [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead, which has [`find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) methods, amongst many others.  And `std::cin` knows how to operate with `std::string`.

For example:

```
#include <string>

void execute()
{
    //start with getting the first word
    std::string first_word;
    std::string::size_type i = input.find(' '); // input is a std::string read with cin, obtaining the command.
    if (i != std::string::npos)
        first_word = input.substr(0, i);
    else
        first_word = input;
    std::cout << first_word << " h ha";
}
```

Comment: when the 'input' is "test input" I still get the error, and there's not even 20 characters there. Why then?

Comment: `cin >> input` doesn't do what you think it does. `cin >>` cannot read into a character array, use `cin.getline()` or `cin.read()` instead. So you are actually processing invalid memory and causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, even if it were working, you are not putting a null terminator at the end of the characters you copy into `first_word`. And as Matt said, your `printf()` statement is not doing what you think it does (but that would not cause stack corruption, just garbage output). Also,